# Wordpress for each loop not working 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to loop over an array but I keep getting the same error :/

Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

my array:

```
$data[]= array('title' => get_the_title( $id ), 
               'link' => get_the_permalink( $id ));
```

My loop:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
    <p><a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I've dumped my array and it looks good so there's probably something wrong with my loop

Comment: try to edit your definition of array to this: `$data= array(...`. I mean, don't use `$data[]`, when you defining array after `=`

Comment: @pes502 Doesn't seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see you have an associative array with keys `title` and `link` so you don't have to call it like an object, simply do this..

```
<?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
    <p><a href="<?php echo $item['link']; ?>"><?php echo $item['title']; ?></a></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to print data object first to look that in data object you have required data.

```
    <?php
         echo '<pre>';
         print_r(data);
         echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```

from that data object you can correct your foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Please use this `foreach` format

```
$data = array('title' => 5, 
               'link' => 5);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

  echo $key;
}
```

Comment: I just get 0 1 2 then

Comment: You have other element (arrays) in `$data[]` ?